# How to update Apollo cache after query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

How can I override a value in the Apollo cache?

I have a graphql query to fetch the user. This returns a user with a default currency. This currency can then be override from a select dropdown.

The query fetches `paymentCurrencies` from an API, then uses a client side resolver to set the first item in the array of `paymentCurrencies` to be the users `currency`

```
query me {
  me {
    username
    currency @client
    paymentCurrencies
  }
}
```

When somebody selects a currency from the dropdown menu, I want to over the users currency with whatever they have selected.

I have something like this so far:

```
const onChange = e => {
  const { value } = e.target
  client.writeData({ user: { currency: value, username, __typename: "User" } })
}
```

I get the following error: `Error writing result to store for query:
 {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"OperationDefinition","operation":"query","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"GeneratedClientQuery"},"selectionSet":null}]}
Cannot read property 'selections' of null`

Is using `writeData` is the correct method or should I be using `writeQuery` or something?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the other answer you probably want a simple query and mutation setup. The client directive is used to extend your schema to hold client-only additional data. From your explanation, it sounds like you explicitly want this data to be syncronised with the server.

```
const ME_QUERY = gql`
  query me {
    me {
      username
      currency
      paymentCurrencies
    }
  }
`;

const CURRENCY_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation setCurrency($currency: String) {
    setCurrency(currency: $currency) {
      me {
        username
        currency
      }
    }
  }
`;

function MyComponent() {
  const { data } = useQuery(ME_QUERY);
  const [setCurrency] = useMutation(CURRENCY_MUTATION);

  const onChange = e => setCurrency({
    variables: { currency: e.currentTarget.value },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{data && data.me.currency}</h2>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        {/* your dropdown logic */}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

You get the idea. Apollo will now automatically update your cache. Make sure your mutation allows to query the updated user object.

For the automatic update to work **your user needs to be recognised by the cache**. You can do that by either adding an id field and selecting it in both the query and the mutation or implementing a `dataIdFromObject` function in Apollo Client 2.x that includes the username for `__typename === 'User'` or by using a type policy in Apollo Client 3.x. Find the [docs here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/).

Comment: So the setCurrency would be a client side resolver mutation? I would still need logic in that resolver that writes the currency to the cache though wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

`writeData` should be used for changing fields at the root, for example:

```
{
  yourState @client
}
```

In this case, you should use writeQuery. Additionally, this logic should really be extracted into a (local) mutation you can then call inside your component. When using `writeQuery`, the basic idea is to grab the existing data, make a copy and then transform it as needed:

```
const { me } = client.readQuery({ query: ME_QUERY })
const data = {
  me: {
    ...me,
    currency: value,
  }
}
client.writeQuery({ query: ME_QUERY, data })
```

You can also use `writeFragment` to directly modify a single instance of an object in the cache. However, you need the object's cache key for this. Because the cache key is derived from the `__typename` and an `id` field, you should **make sure the query includes an id field first**. This is good practice regardless to ensure your cache can be updated easily (see [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#data-normalization) for more details). Then you can do something like this:

```
client.writeFragment({
  id: 'User:42',
  fragment: gql`
    fragment UserCurrency on User {
      currency @client
    }
  `,
  data: {
    currency: value,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

For persistent change (sync to server) you should just change user setting using mutation.

For session aware change - don't use user settings - copy this (from logged user properties) to **separate** value in global app state (redux/mobx or as in this case apollo [local state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/)).

In both cases rare problem can be with updating many components using changed data.

Redux/mobx solves this automatically.
Apollo HOCs won't rerender.
Hooks - updates partially (only the one with `useQuery` and `useMutation` pair), others will be updated only when rerendered.
Components build with `<Query/>` creates internally an observable then they will be updated, too.

Mutation have `update` and `refetchQueries` parameters for.
There is also a [package](https://github.com/ecerroni/apollo-cache-updater) for more complex use cases.